# How should we handle pandas udf with differing input lengths in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark - I want a function to take in the two inputs of two dataframes of differing sizes - what would be the best way to do so? (If both dataframes have the same columns but differing lengths)

I am also assuming pandas udf can only be applied on a single pyspark dataframe (please correct me if I'm wrong) - so one approach may be to  append it to one of the dataframes and in the udf, use iloc to break it apart at those indices to get back the two columns. But is this the best way?

I have the below code for reference but without the appending - to give insight on what I'm trying to do

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, struct, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField("num", IntegerType(), True)])

data1 = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema)
data2 = [(4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema)

@pandas_udf(DoubleType())
def udf_test(df1, df2):
    val1, _ = some_func(df1['num'], df2['num'])
    return pd.Series(val1)
```

Comment: Show us how the output should look like. That helps a lot.

Comment: the line `val1, _ = some_func(df1['num'], df2['num'])` is a bit confusing to me. does `some_func` return multiple values?

Comment: @DerekO It may or may not, consider it as a blackbox. Main intention is to somehow even get those two df into the udf for further processing.

Comment: @arudsekaberne Output isn't a concern for me, it's getting the input inside the function that's confusing me (if that's even possible) You can assume any output from the above function if you really have to.